# Banshee doesn't like opening websites

Tags: 10.10, banshee

I have come across two bugs (which will be added to launchpad if it's not resolved here)

1. When I open any of the websites in Banshee Amazon or Miro Guide as soon as the site is finished loading it crashes Banshee.
2. If I play any video local or remote it will show 1 frame maybe 0.5 sec of video then I get a black screen and audio continues in the backgound.

   - Specs & Details

I have a Fujitsu Amilo 1718 laptop with 2 gig of ram (original 1 gig) graphics is provided by ATI Radeon Xpress 200M (don't laugh it works with compiz....just)

I have a link to the output of `banshee --debug` [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/574953/).

Don't have time to read? Here are the highlights:

```
[2 Warn  11:52:34.814] Caught an exception - System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
```

then a bit later

```
Debug info from gdb:

Could not attach to process.  If your uid matches the uid of the target
process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try
again as the root user.  For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
ptrace: Operation not permitted.

=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

Aborted
```

Not music to my ears as you can expect. The version I am using is 1.9.4 from the daily ppa but these bugs happen in any version of banshee from 1.8.1 and up. So if any one has come across a fix for this problem please share!!

**Additional info**

Both VLC and Miro work on my system so there isn't a system wide problem with video and I haven't mentioned mono so no trolling it will get voted down.

**Edit 1/2**

Ok so half way there I added the webkit teams ppa `ppa:webkit-team/ppa` to my software sources and updated. The result is Banshee no longer crashes when opening sites. However its is still unable to play video even after disabling gapless playback as per Michaels instructions so Halfway there but not the full Banana.

Comment: Glad the webkit issue is fixed.  As far as the video issue goes, it looks like gapless might not be the cause of that bug after all -- see my updated answer.  Is the problem happening with all file formats, or only specific (probably H.264-encoded mp4) files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This sounds like an issue with the version of webkit-gtk or webkit-sharp installed on your system.  It's either a bug in Banshee, or a problem with the packaging, but either way, you should probably report it on Launchpad.
2. This could be [Bug 617957](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=617957).  Does the problem happen with all types of video, or is it specific to certain types?  It was thought that the problem might be related to gapless playback, but based on [Comment 16](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=617957#c16) there, that may not actually be the cause.

Comment: Hi Michael thanks for the update. Unfortunately this happens with all videos from old avi to new mkv the symptom is every thing works fine up to about 0.5 sec or maybe less in to the video then the video goes black while the audio continues in the background. I will open a bug at launchpad this weekend.

Comment: Hmm, that's no good.  Can Totem play the files without a problem?  VLC packages its own video codecs, and I'm not sure what Miro does, but Totem and Banshee would share gstreamer libraries for playing videos.  *In theory* if it works in one, it should work in the other.  If the videos work in Totem, but not Banshee, you might want to skip Launchpad and report the bug directly to the source: http://banshee.fm/file-bugs

Comment: Reinstalled Totem which has no problems Banshee still has problems so its off to banshee.fm for me.

Comment: Recently upgraded to Natty 11.04 and everything works out of the box. Funnily enough I had a similar issue with window previews in kde I'm feeling some compiz (jealousy) bug at work. It seams the work done to get compiz up to scratch for unity has benefited other areas.